# Где лучше проверять данные для алгоритма на валидность?

Tags: java, ооп, исключения

Я реализовал алгоритм. Этому алгоритмы на вход надо подавать только положительные числа. Сейчас я проверяю положительность чисел в GUI и если они не положительные вывожу предупреждение и прошу заново ввести числа.

Не лучше ли перенести эту проверку в сам класс алгоритма? Что бы перед началом выполнения он проверял числа и бросал исключение, если есть отрицательные. И поставить `throws` на метод. А в GUI взять вызов метода алгоритма, в котором как раз бросаю исключение в try-cacth и в catch прописать нужное мне сообщение об ошибке для пользователя?

Answer (score 5):

Если "алгоритм" работает только с положительными числами, то он должен это и проверить. "Алгоритм" может предоставлять методы для верификации своих аргументов. И в этом случае gui может вызвать этот метод, вывести красиво сообщения об ошибке.  А может просто обработать исключения. Почему так? Ваш "алгоритм" вполне возможно нужно будет использовать из других "мест", например, в консольном приложении или для веб приложения. И не факт, что пользователи "алгоритма" всё напишут правильно.

**UPD**

Есть такой принцип - DRY SPOT - do not repeat yourself (не повторяй себя) and Single Point of Truth  (единый источник истины). Поэтому, если два куска кода будут знать, как проверить параметры - рано или поздно будет беда.

Comment: Категорически не рекомендуется использовать наследование только для того, чтобы избежать повторения кода.

Comment: как это связано с моим постом?

Comment: Так, что DRY - не единственный принцип, которым надо руководствоваться, и не стоит при следовании ему пренебрегать также и остальными принципами ООП. Не стоит воспринимать этот коммент как агрессию в вашу сторону: мы тут на StackOverflow коллективно отвечаем на вопросы и дополняем друг друга, как считаем нужным.

Comment: Я не воспринимаю это как агресию - просто у комментария нет связки с текстом ответа. А вот к соседнему ответу он подходит.

Comment: Возможно, вы правы, и я действительно думал о чем-то своем, оставляя этот коммент :) Но ваш коммент направляет внимание читателя на DRY, и я добавляю предостережение. Для меня связь есть.

Comment: @ПавелКрижановский, а про то, что не стоит пренебрегать остальными принципами ООП из за DRY, это общий совет? Или это связано с ответом? Если я буду делать как в ответе написано, я пренебрегу каким то из принципов ООП? Я просто не вижу каким.

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров а это уже смотря как именно вы будете ему следовать. Например, касательно "алгоритм может предоставлять методы для верификации": а если клиент не знает о методах верификации? Или пренебрег их вызовом? Что тогда должен делать "алгоритм"? И мы приходим к первоначальной задаче :) Я считаю, что вызывающий код в любом случае сможет обработать и красиво вывести сообщения об ошибках, хоть через методы верификации, хоть через обработку исключений, но логичнее и правильнее бросать исключения: их невозможно забыть обработать (или пренебречь этим).

Answer (score 3):

Для больших проектов применяется подход, согласно которому рекомендуется отделять логику работы от логики проверок. Заключается в следующем:

- Пишем класс, отвечающий за логику, и ловящий исключения только нижележащих слоев. Класс никак не проверяет переданные ему значения на корректность: падает при `NullPointerException`, делениях на 0 и т.д. В вашем случае при передаче отрицательных чисел должен бросать своё исключение (можно унаследовать его от `IllegalArgumentException` или `InvalidParameterException`).
- Пишем к нему классы-обертки с нужными нам проверками.

Таким образом, если ваш код будет использоваться сторонними программистами, они сами смогут обработать исключения, которые бросает ваш класс, так, как посчитают нужным. **А может, они его расширят (унаследуют) для работы вашей логики и с отрицательными числами, и тогда не надо будет встраивать в него проверку на положительность. И тут ой, беда: вы уже её встроили, и придется переписывать ваш класс.**

> Класс никак не проверяет переданные ему значения на корректность

Имеется в виду, что он не обрабатывает неправильные значения, скрывая их от вызывающих методов. И предложенное вами решение обрабатывать исключения в GUI допустимо, если судьба вашего класса - умереть в этом приложении :) Если же вы будете использовать его хоть где-то ещё, в более крупных приложениях, сами его расширять (наследовать), или использовать в командной разработке, или где-то публиковать - сделайте для него классы-обертки, проверяющие входные данные различными способами.

Comment: можно всегда использовать делегирование. И никаких проблем.
Но, с другой стороны, не для всех алгоритмов можно написать версию, которая работает со всем возможным диапазоном чисел.

Comment: @ПавелКрижановский, очень интересно. Но не очень понимаю( получается сторонним то программистам как раз лучше пользоваться классами-обертками, что бы не писать самостоятельно обработчики. А вот если надо расширить поведение, то унаследовать исходный класс, что бы там никакие проверки не мешались, правильно понимаю?

Comment: То есть получается середина между обработкой прямо в алгоритме и не обработкой вообще, возложением этого на клиента? А тут мы как бы предоставляем и клиентам возможность обработать (хотя не понятно зачем им это нужно) но и предоставляем возможность воспользоваться оболочкой. Хотя тут не получается некоторого усложнения? Клиенты должны знать еще и об оболочке, знать зачем она нужна

Comment: Вот именно. Сторонние программисты смогут сами решить, использовать ли предоставленные вами "стандартные" классы-обертки с "типичными" проверками, которые вы, конечно, будете поставлять в том же пакете, или же ваш оригинальный класс с логикой.

Comment: Клиентам в любом случае придется что-нибудь узнать, чтобы использовать любые ваши классы. Вы же знаете и о классе `ArrayList`, и о классе `LinkedList`, и об интерфейсе `List`, несмотря на то, что классы, реализующие `List`, вроде как содержат всё необходимое? :)

Comment: @KoVadim, а можете насчет делегирования пожалуйста подсказать? То есть если надо расширить первоначальную логику, например для использования еще и с отрицательными числами, то мы создаем новый класс, и там нужно вызывать метод старого (это же делегирование). Но в методе старого нам мешается проверка. Тупик. Видимо что то я не так понимаю(

Comment: И тут я говорю: вот видите, нужен класс, не содержащий проверок :)

Comment: В новом классе проверяем параметры. Если мы можем их обработать - просто обрабатываем, если нет - спрашиваем в старого класса, может ли он их обработать (а для этого есть метод!), если может - вызываем его и возвращаем результат. Хотя возможен и другой вариант - вызываем старый метод, если он бросил исключения, то вызываем новый метод и наружу исключений не отдаем.

И содержит ли старый класс проверки или нет - не имеет значения.

Comment: Это обычное расширение (наследование) базового класса.
Нет, имеет значение: если старый класс содержит проверки и не бросает исключений при отрицательных значениях, мы вообще можем не узнать, что он работает только с положительными, и нам надо как-то его расширить.

Comment: не имеет. Перед вызовом старого класса мы сами можем сделать проверки. "мы вообще можем не узнать, что он работает только с положительными" - это проблема документации и плохого дизайна.

Comment: Так мы о дизайне "старого класса" тут и говорим. И о том, что такое "плохой дизайн", и как избежать связанных с ним проблем.

Comment: Считаю, что автор получил более чем достаточно информации по своему вопросу в результате нашей дискуссии, добавить мне больше нечего, так что удаляюсь.